# Prove Bernoulli Task

Tags: bernoulli-polynomials

Prove for $\ n\ge100,n\ge50,n\ge49 \ $that the following is true:

> $$\ 101^{n}>100^{n}+99^{n} \ $$

Prove for $\ n\ge100,n\ge50,n\ge49 \ $

I know it’s somehow connected with Bernoulli; however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Comment: The inequality is true for $n=49$, but it's false for $n=50$ and $n=100$.  In fact, $101^{50}-100^{50}-99^{50} = -3022603911549554928$ and $101^{100}-100^{100}-99^{100} = -831363304571293664$.

Comment: Yeah,  but how can you prove it without calculation?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Are you sure?  I think $101^{50}-100^{50}-99^{50}$ may be about $+3.96\times 10^{98}$ and it only gets bigger from there.

Comment: My point is that you *can't* prove something ($n = 50, 100$) that is false.

Comment: @GNUSupporter  If it is true for $n$ it is true for anything greater than $n$. To see that, write it as $1≥\left( \frac {100}{101}\right)^n+\left( \frac {99}{101}\right)^n$

Comment: It is totally right for all the conditions, but I need to prove it using some theory.

Comment: I see it as false for $n=48$ but true for all $n≥49$.

Comment: @Henry ,lulu OIC.  Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I don't see how to avoid the calculation for $n=49$.  Writing it my way, with $n=48$ the right hand is $1.003141$ and at $n=49$ the right hand is $0.989418$.  It's very close!

Comment: @lulu can’t we use induction?

Comment: Induction has to start somewhere.  Like I say, once you know it for $n=49$ you are done.  But I don't see a way to make it obvious for $49$ ...which doesn't mean there isn't one, of course.  I mean, writing it as you did, we see that $101^{49}-100^{49}-99^{49}\approx 1.72\times 10^{96}$ which certainly makes it look less close than my method does.

Comment: @lulu I also tried to use the binomial theorem and Bernoulli inequality, but it didn’t work out.

Comment: There could be a proof if you could show $e^{49/101} \gt \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which is in fact true

Comment: The binomial theorem might work.   Write $101^{49}=(100+1)^{49},99^{49}=(100-1)^{49}$.

Comment: @Henry how exactly can I show it?

Comment: I can get the binomial theorem to do it for $n=50$...not instantly clear that I can tighten the method to get $n=49$.  I'll write it up below.

Comment: @Valerie: no idea without a calculator, but it would imply $e^{-49/101} +e^{-2 \times 49/101} \lt 1 $ and thus $\left(1- \frac {1}{101}\right)^{49}+\left(1 -\frac {2}{101}\right)^{49} \lt 1$

Comment: Just added an argument to get $n=49$.  It's significantly messier and should definitely be checked for arithmetic blunder.

Comment: @lulu yeah, thank you very much. Great that some of my thoughts are actually not that pointless. I’ll see what my professor thinks about it tomorrow.

Comment: Good luck. $\quad $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show it for $n=50$.  That will, of course, show it for $n≥50$ though not immediately for $n=49$.

Writing $101=100+1,99=100-1$ we see that $$101^{50}-99^{50}=\sum_{i=0}^{50}\left(1-(-1)^i\right)\binom {50}i100^{50-i}=2\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom {50}{2k+1}100^{50-2k-1} $$

Now, the first term in the sum is $$\binom {50}1100^{50}=50\times 100^{49}=\frac 12\times 100^{50}$$ so we are done.

Perhaps some tightening of this will suffice for $n=49$, but I did not try.  As stated in the comments, the claim is false if $n=48$.

Added:  The same method works for $n=49$ but you need the first two terms in the sum.  Specifically, the same method shows that 
$$101^{49}-99^{49}=\sum_{i=0}^{49}\left(1-(-1)^i\right)\binom {49}i100^{49-i}=2\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom {49}{2k+1}100^{49-2k-1} $$ Now, the first term in the sum is $$49\times 100^{48}$$ and the second term is $$\binom {49}3\times 100^{46}=18424\times 100^{46}>100^2\times 100^{46}=100^{48}$$ and adding these two terms completes the argument as before.